# HtmlHelper in .NET Core 2.0 with appsettings being injected in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I may be on a dead-end path, so I'm hoping that someone can either tell me to "turn around!" or "keep going!" - I'm attempting to convert an HTML helper from an ASP.NET 5 app into a .NET Core 2.0 app. I ran into trouble when calling the helper in an extension class. First, I read that .NET Core uses DI for getting appsettings into separate classes, so I set up the extension class with DI:

```
private readonly AppSettings _appsettings;

public HtmlHelperExtensions2(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    _appsettings = appSettings.Value;
}
```

And I'm able to return items from appSettings.json. The problem is that to use DI I needed to remove the "static" references from the class signature, so I also had to remove the "this" reference from the helper call:

```
public void HelpPanel(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string thingId, string language)
{ }
```

Otherwise I get a compile error. But without the "this" reference the call expects a new HtmlHelper.

So I'm trying to get past this, if I can in fact get past it. Is this the right path or am I on a dead-end road here? Do I need to use something else in Core besides HtmlHelpers? I can't determine if they're even supported in Core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the request's `IServiceProvider` from an instance of `HtmlHelper` and use the [Service Locator <strike>anti</strike>-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)  to resolve instances from the DI container. Brace yourself for an example (it's a bit of a "train wreck"):

```
var appSettings = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
    .GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>()
    .Value;
```

Disclaimer: Statics and the Service Locator pattern are a little contentious. [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.0) don't use statics and support Dependency Injection, so you might want to consider switching to one of these if/when the time is right.